# function writing in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe(df) with only three columns  showing ideal weight(x) in kgs (column1), age(y) in years (column 2) and gender(z) (column 3, boy coded 1 & girl coded 2) for school students. I want to write a function for getting what is ideal weight of a school student at given age and gender. My novice attempt is shown below:

```
idealwt<-function(age,gender){

  age=df$y

  gender=df$z

  idealwt = df$x[age==df$y & gender==df$z]

  return(idealwt)
}
```

However, above function returns the whole vector instead of specific value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the OP's function results from creating the objects 'age' and 'gender' which is also the arguments of the function.  So, in essence, we are comparing the `df$y == df$y` and `df$z == df$z` which results in getting TRUE for all the elements and output is the whole vector.  Instead, we can define the function without `age = df$y` and `gender = df$z`

```
idealwt<-function(age,gender){
  df$x[age==df$y & gender==df$z]

} 

idealwt(12, 2)
#[1] 38 42
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(45, 38, 55, 33, 42), y = c(15, 12, 18, 14, 12), 
                z = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Tons and tons of thank, my last one-month dilemma is finally over. Superb!!!! sincerest regards